# Spring Data doesn't log findById

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Having created a `Customer` entity and repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

and bean that saves and selects an entity:

```
@Component
public class BeanClass
{
  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository repository;

  @Transactional
  public void tran()
  {
    Customer entity = new Customer("Jack3", "Bauer");
    Customer save1 = repository.save(entity);
    Optional<Customer> byId = repository.findById(Long.valueOf(save1.getId()));
    System.out.println("customer " + byId);
  }
}
```

I specified query logging `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE` in configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/demospring?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=*
spring.datasource.password=*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
```

I don't see `select` query in logs, there's only logging of the entity being persisted:

```
2019-12-28 16:29:56.732  INFO 17623 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-12-28 16:29:57.331  INFO 17623 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.526 seconds (JVM running for 5.198)
2019-12-28 16:29:57.382 DEBUG 17623 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into customer (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)
customer Optional[Customer[id=73, firstName='Jack3', lastName='Bauer']]
2019-12-28 16:30:03.455  INFO 17623 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-12-28 16:30:03.457  INFO 17623 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-12-28 16:30:03.462  INFO 17623 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication
{
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
  @Autowired
  BeanClass bc;
  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository)
  {

    return (args) -> {
      bc.tran();
    };
  }
}
```

Can `findById` be logged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's expected: it doesn't need to execute any query, since you just persisted the entity, in the same transaction: it's in the first-level cache.

By the way, it hasn't even been inserted to the database yet at that point.

If you executed one transaction to save the entity, and another one to find it by ID, then you would see the SQL query being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Reason first level hibernate cache.

findById is not logged because it is in the same transaction (that was started while entering the method tran()) and same Hibernate session. findById's select query is not executed as object is already loaded in current session.